# Need help doing Palindrome testing

Tags: c++

Hi guys im doing a palindrome test exercise. I need to have 3 functions, one changes all uppercase to Lcase, one which filters out non-alphabets, and a boolean which checks if palindrome is true or not. This is my code so far

```
        class palindrome
{
public:
    palindrome();
    void RemovNonCase();
    void LowerCase();
    bool IsaPalindrome(std::string phrase);
private:
    std::string word;
};
#endif 

// cpp file
palindrome::palindrome()
{

}

void palindrome::RemovNonCase()
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] = '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
                || (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            word[j++] = word[i];
        }
        word[j] = '\0';
    }
}

void palindrome::LowerCase()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.size() - 1); i++)
    { // lower case testing
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
}
bool palindrome::IsaPalindrome(string phrase)
{
    word = phrase;
    RemovNonCase();
    LowerCase();

    int len = word.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[len - i - 1])
        {
            return false; // testing if the string is a palindrome
        }

    }
    return true;
}

// main
int main()
{

    string phrase;
    cout << "Enter a word or a sentence" << endl;
    getline(cin, phrase);

    palindrome obj1;

    if (obj1.IsaPalindrome(phrase))
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
```

When I run this, no matter what I type, I only get 'NO'. I'm not sure where my boolean function is not working that i'm only getting no as an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Typo: `for (int i=0; word[i]='\0';i++)` `word[i] = '\0'` is an assignment. Ooops. You want `word[i] == '\0'`.

Comment: also please use a proper indentation

Comment: Popped the code into an editor to hit it with a formatter and, because I have compile on save turned on, the compiler spat out : *warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value* over `for (int i = 0; word[i] = '\0'; i++)`. Trust the compiler. It knows things.

Comment: You CAN NOT remove stuff from std::string this way. You need to forget C, all of it. std::string is not C string. C++ is not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `RemovNonCase` function the string gets broken. There you overwrite characters at the beginning of the string with `\0` depending on the number of non characters.

```
"ab55ba" => "\0\055ba"
```

Here is a possible (but not fully optimized) C++11 implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

class Palindrome
{
public:

    static void RemoveNonAlphabet(std::string& phrase)
    {
        auto toRemove = std::remove_if(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), 
            [](const char c) {return !std::isalpha(c);});
        phrase.erase(toRemove, phrase.end());
    }

    static void ToLowerCase(std::string& phrase)
    {
        for (auto& c : phrase)
        {
            c = std::tolower(c);
        }
    }

    static bool IsPalindrome(std::string phrase)
    {
        RemoveNonAlphabet(phrase);
        ToLowerCase(phrase);

        auto start = phrase.begin();
        auto rStart = phrase.rbegin();
        for (; start != phrase.end(); ++start, ++rStart)
        {
            if (*start != *rStart)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string phrase;
    std::cout << "Enter a word or sentence: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, phrase);
    std::cout 
        << (Palindrome::IsPalindrome(std::move(phrase)) ? "YES" : "NO")
        << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter a word or sentence: AbcBa
YES
```

Comment: Two minor notes: (1) going past the middle of the string in the main palindrome checking loop wastes cycles; and (2) a class with all static members doesn't have too much sense since we have namespaces.

Comment: Agreed. As I have written it's not a optimized code as I assume performance is not the crucial criteria here. But nevertheless you're right of course.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't passed  the arguments into the lowercase and remove non case functions. Hence the output given was not correct. Please compare my code:

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;

class palindrome
{
public:
    palindrome();
    void RemovNonCase(string);  //changed
    void LowerCase(string);     //changed
    bool IsaPalindrome(std::string phrase);
private:
    std::string word;
};

// cpp file
palindrome::palindrome()
{

}

void palindrome::RemovNonCase(string word)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] = '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
                || (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            word[j++] = word[i];
        }
        word[j] = '\0';
    }
}

void palindrome::LowerCase(string word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.size() - 1); i++)
    { // lower case testing
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
}

bool palindrome::IsaPalindrome(string phrase)
{
    word = phrase;
    RemovNonCase(phrase);  //changed
    LowerCase(phrase);     //changed

    int len = word.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[len - i - 1])
        {
            return false; // testing if the string is a palindrome
        }

    }
    return true;
}

// main
int main()
{

    string phrase;
    cout << "Enter a word or a sentence" << endl;
    getline(cin, phrase);


    palindrome obj1;


    if (obj1.IsaPalindrome(phrase))
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}
```

here are the output pics... the program is totally correct....if there are any errors do share the screenshots: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1shHBhFsiTsq2-ZvOpcVhTt4hH_xjdQQW
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u_eT4d7Q1L0j63j-IpPhtZ18KsfIJJuK

Comment: Have you tested this code? It's all wrong.

Comment: yes!! I can show you the output even

Comment: thanks a lot. I just assumed that the function would filter the argument by itself. This one works better, but it doesn't work if i try a sentence with a space.

Comment: Sorry but it worked fine in my system. But i am unable to share the images of the output because of low reputation

Comment: https://ideone.com/0qTJ9I

Comment: `RemovNonCase` and `LowerCase` do absolutely nothing. All their effort is spent modifying local variables that go out of scope and die. The compiler eliminates them.

Comment: you can check without arguments the output shown is wrong while in case with arguments the output is totally correct for words as well as sentences

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u_eT4d7Q1L0j63j-IpPhtZ18KsfIJJuK

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1shHBhFsiTsq2-ZvOpcVhTt4hH_xjdQQW

Comment: really strange because it doesnt work in mine.

Comment: Quick demonstration of `LowerCase`: https://ideone.com/W0pfwl

Comment: i dont know why

Comment: i would recommend to use Visual Studio or a terminal to execute

Comment: user4581301 in that case i suppose i need to pass by reference?

Comment: @swapnil Just ignore the answer. It is trying to fix a non-problem that needs no fixing, and introduces a new problem that was not there to begin with. It does not fix any of the problems that were there originally.

Comment: well I figured it out eventually. I used the call by reference on RemovNOnCase and LowerCase. Thanks everyone for your help!!!

Comment: All your examples that do work would also work if you just removed RemovNonCase and LowerCase altogether.

Comment: @swapnil do as you wish but this answer is **not** helping you.

Comment: @n.m yeah you're right.